# How to re-sort different column groups to align each other, using a mutual column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

My data is out of order, meaning that some rows need to be shifted up or down to match a certain order. The correct order is reflected by a column with certain values. Those values correspond to a column that belongs to the disordered group of columns.

Since there's a mutual column, I'm looking for a way to do this reordering "internally" within the dataframe. Is there an easy way to do it using `tidyr` or `dplyr`, in one `%>%` pipe?

### Example

I asked 3 people to rate how much they like either dogs, cats, or rabbits, on a scale of 1-5. Each person answered the questions in a different order than the other people.

```r
set.seed(2020)

df <- data.frame(respondent_id = c("ttt", "ttt", "ttt",
                             "xxx", "xxx", "xxx",
                             "zzz", "zzz", "zzz"),
           animal = c("dog", "cat", "rabbit",
                          "dog", "cat", "rabbit",
                          "dog", "cat", "rabbit"),
           rating = sample(1:5, size = 9, replace = TRUE),
           order = c("cat", "rabbit", "dog",
                     "dog", "rabbit", "cat",
                     "rabbit", "cat", "dog"))

df

##   respondent_id animal rating  order
## 1           ttt    dog      4    cat
## 2           ttt    cat      4 rabbit
## 3           ttt rabbit      1    dog
## 4           xxx    dog      1    dog
## 5           xxx    cat      4 rabbit
## 6           xxx rabbit      2    cat
## 7           zzz    dog      1  rabbit
## 8           zzz    cat      5    cat
## 9           zzz rabbit      2    dog
```

- Columns `animal` and `order` are the basis for aligning the data.
- When grouping by `respondent_id`, I'd like to move `animal` and `rating` columns (together) up or down so that the value in `animal` will match the value in `order`.

### Desired Output

```r
  respondent_id animal rating  order
1           ttt    cat      4    cat
2           ttt rabbit      1 rabbit
3           ttt    dog      4    dog
4           xxx    dog      1    dog
5           xxx rabbit      2 rabbit
6           xxx    cat      4    cat
7           zzz rabbit      2 rabbit
8           zzz    cat      5    cat
9           zzz    dog      1    dog
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `slice` and `match`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(respondent_id) %>%
  slice(match(order, animal)) %>%
  mutate(order = animal)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#> # Groups:   respondent_id [3]
#>   respondent_id animal rating order 
#>   <chr>         <chr>   <int> <chr> 
#> 1 ttt           cat         4 cat   
#> 2 ttt           rabbit      1 rabbit
#> 3 ttt           dog         4 dog   
#> 4 xxx           dog         1 dog   
#> 5 xxx           rabbit      2 rabbit
#> 6 xxx           cat         4 cat   
#> 7 zzz           rabbit      2 rabbit
#> 8 zzz           cat         5 cat   
#> 9 zzz           dog         1 dog
```

Comment: thanks, @Paul. Your solution works with the toy data I provided in the question, but for some reason I can't apply this method to my actual data. Would you mind explaining the principles underlying your code? I understand what `match(order, animal)` does, but can't understand how `slice()` operates on that, and the `mutate` at the end is unclear to me as well. Thanks :)

Comment: `match(order, animal)` gets the row numbers in the correct order for each group. `slice` simply selects the rows in the order specified by `match`. For example, the first row selected is `ttt, cat, 4, rabbit`. `mutate(order = animal)` updates the `order` column so that it becomes `ttt, cat, 4, cat`.